# Gitlab customized personal profile readme for an internal repo

Tags: gitlab, readme

I want to add a special profile repo to my gitlab profile. To make it I need to add a public repo wtih the same name as my profile. However my organisation only lets me create internal repos. So is there any way to create profile repo with internal visibility?